# How it works when the action result size is bigger than the machines memory?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Storage and memory size of a machine on which pyspark collect()(action) is 1gb. But my resultant file size is 4gb(which is stored in 4 partitions of size 1gb each). Now how is my 4gb result is going to return output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your job will probably crush on OOO error.
You can either write the result to HDFS and read it from there instead of collect ( collect is bad practice)
or you can give more memory to your driver machine ( the Driver will store the collect data)

Comment: why collect is bad practice , any link ?

Comment: Spark is supposed to work with large data sets, usually if there's a good reason for you to use Spark collect should fail because a single machine shouldnt be able to contain all the data in the same time.